# Error when streamming mp3 use mediaplayer

Tags: android

I use mediaplayer streaming music(mp3, m4a...) with the code fragment shown below:

```
mediaPlayer!!.setDataSource("http://www.ne.jp/asahi/music/myuu/wave/menuettm.mp3")
mediaPlayer!!.prepare()
mediaPlayer!!.setOnPreparedListener {
  mediaPlayer!!.start()
  mediaPlayer!!.seekTo(0)
}
```

but it does not work and and results in the error shown next.

```
019-04-26 12:54:22.150 6520-6571/jp.iodata.cdrecooem E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8192; index=8192
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.writeUtf8(Buffer.java:818)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.writeUtf8(Buffer.java:793)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.writeUtf8(RealBufferedSink.java:57)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.writeRequest(Http1xStream.java:167)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.writeRequestHeaders(Http1xStream.java:123)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:593)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:471)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
    at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.seekTo(MediaHTTPConnection.java:212)
    at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.getMIMEType(MediaHTTPConnection.java:385)
    at android.media.IMediaHTTPConnection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaHTTPConnection.java:88)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

Comment: Cleaned up code and grammer

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you maybe forgot to add uses permission to your manifest file

Add this permission to your android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> And then you can proceed your work

```
 val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://www.ne.jp/asahi/music/myuu/wave/menuettm.mp3")
        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener {

            mediaPlayer.start()
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0)
        }
```

Comment: bug still occurs

Comment: my pleasure and sorry it doesn't help

Comment: you added null assertion you can handle it non nullable , it is working exactly fine here with the permission in what minimum sdk you are running ?